# Telegraf: [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin read: connection reset by peer

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes-helm, telegraf

I am using the SQL Server plugin with the telegraf helm chart in the AKS cluster in order to monitor SQL servers that are on premise. My values file is as follows is as follows:

```
## Exposed telegraf configuration
## For full list of possible values see `/docs/all-config-values.yaml` and `/docs/all-config-values.toml`
## ref: https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.1/administration/configuration/
config:
  outputs:
    - health:
        service_address: "http://:8888"
    - influxdb:
        urls:
          - "http://monitoring-influxdb.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:8086"
        database: "telegraf"
        username: admin
        password: admin
  inputs: 
    - sqlserver:
        servers:
          - "Server="XX.XX.XX.XX;Port=1433;User Id=sql_telegraf;Password=XXXXXXXX;app name=telegraf;log=1;"
```

However, I seem to be getting the following error all the time:

> 2020-02-20T04:22:26Z W! [agent] [inputs.sqlserver] did not complete
>   within its interval
>   2020-02-20T04:22:36Z W! [agent] [inputs.sqlserver] did not
>   complete within its interval
>   2020-02-20T04:22:36Z I! ERROR: Intercepted panic read tcp
>   YY.YY.YY.YY:45556->XX.XX.XX.XX:1433: read: connection reset by peer                                                                                                              │ │ 2020-02-20T04:22:36Z E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: read
>   tcp YY.YY.YY.YY:45556->XX.XX.XX.XX:1433: read: connection reset by
>   peer
>   2020-02-20T04:22:46Z W! [agent] [inputs.sqlserver] did not complete within its interval
>   2020-02-20T04:22:56Z W! [agent] [inputs.sqlserver] did not complete within its interval
>   2020-02-20T04:22:57Z I! ERROR: Intercepted panic read tcp YY.YY.YY.YY:45980->XX.XX.XX.XX:1433: read: connection reset by peer
>   2020-02-20T04:22:57Z E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: read
>   tcp YY.YY.YY.YY:45980->XX.XX.XX.XX:1433: read: connection reset by peer
>   2020-02-20T04:23:01Z I! ERROR: BeginRead failed read tcp
>   YY.YY.YY.YY:45380->XX.XX.XX.XX:1433: read: connection reset by peer
>   2020-02-20T04:23:01Z E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: read
>   tcp YY.YY.YY.YY:45380->XX.XX.XX.XX:1433: read: connection reset by peer
>   2020-02-20T04:23:06Z W! [agent] [inputs.sqlserver] did not complete within its interval
>   2020-02-20T04:23:08Z I! ERROR: Intercepted panic read tcp
>   YY.YY.YY.YY:45374->XX.XX.XX.XX:1433: read: connection reset by peer
>   2020-02-20T04:23:08Z E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: read
>   tcp YY.YY.YY.YY:45374->XX.XX.XX.XX:1433: read: connection reset by peer